# Projects Vs Targets for a client-server model in XCode 5.0 Workspace

Tags: sockets, xcode5

I am writing a socket application using the client-server model in plain C using Xcode 5.0 on my Mac OS X 10.8.5. Would it be better to have 2 projects in the same workspace, or have 2 targets in one project? Unfortunately the link in the answer here [Workspace with multiple projects or one project with multiple targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11641935/workspace-with-multiple-projects-or-one-project-with-multiple-targets) is no longer live - looked like a potential answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether this question can be concisely answered in a forum like this because a lot of the answer will depend on your project, how you and your team work with it, and what sort of hardware you develop on. But here are some considerations:

1. Will there be a lot of code shared between them? If so, you then have the option of either making the shared code into a separate project or target which generates a framework and including that framework in both the client and server target or project. If you factor out the shared code into a separate project you can then use it in other projects besides just the client and server. If it's a target in the same project, then it's much harder to share.
2. Do you have a large amount of code? My experience on a very large project where we used a single workspace containing dozens of large projects was that Xcode becomes painful to use in that situation even with good hardware.

My feeling is that if your project is fairly small, then it doesn't really matter which you use. If it's a larger project, I'd go with the single project containing targets. If you want to have shared code that you can re-use outside of the client and server, go with the separate projects in a single workspace.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others; I came across another answer which says that targets should be used for refactoring code within a project for other hardware. Whereas the workspace environment (using projects) is better suited to sharing files and working with the client-server model.